# Merge Function for two arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort

Merge Function for two arrays, The function is not working properly and doesn't give the required answer. I want that the sorted arrays are merged up as it is the function saying, but it doesn't work.

```
var Merge = function(array,array1,array2)
{
    var n_array = array.length;
    var n_array1 = array1.length;
    var i = j = k = 0;
    while(i < n_array && j < n_array1)
    {
        if(array[i] <= array2[j])
        {
            array2[k] = array[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            array2[k] = array1[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
        k = k + 1;
    }
    while(i < n_array)
    {
        array2[k] = array[i];
        i = i + 1;
        k = k + 1;
    }
    while(j < n_array1)
    {
        array2[k] = array1[j];
        j = j + 1;
        k = k + 1;
    }
    return array2;
};

array = [1,3,5,7];
array1 = [2,4,6,8];
array2 = [];
var result = Merge(array,array1,array2);
console.log("The array is sorted is " + result);
```

Why my code give an answer:
**The array is sorted is 2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Merge = function(array,array1,array2)
{
    var n_array = array.length;
    var n_array1 = array1.length;
    var i = j = k = 0;
    while(i < n_array && j < n_array1)
    {
        if(array[i] <= array1[j])
        {
            array2[k] = array[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            array2[k] = array1[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
        k = k + 1;
    }
    while(i < n_array)
    {
        array2[k] = array[i];
        i = i + 1;
        k = k + 1;
    }
    while(j < n_array1)
    {
        array2[k] = array1[j];
        j = j + 1;
        k = k + 1;
    }
    return array2;
};

array = [1,3,5,7];
array1 = [2,4,6,8];
array2 = [];
var result = Merge(array,array1,array2);
console.log("The array is sorted is " + result);
```

It Works :)
This is the edited solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Assignment is to not use push like functions, What`s wrong in above logic can you explain above code of mine , Why I don`t get solution

Comment: Now it returns but didn't sort the arrays.

Comment: Your final issue that I can spot is you've made a typo in your first if-statement. You're comparing `array` to `array2` instead of `array1`

Answer (score 0):

While the fix for your code is mentioned above, that is a lot of lines for just doing a merge and sort. If you know you will be dealing with numbers you could use the following:

```
var arr = [1, 10, 22];
var arr1 = [20, 17, 3];
var arr2 = arr.concat(arr1);

sortAsc(arr2);

function sortAsc(arrayToSort){
    return arrayToSort.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;
    });
}
```